# Generate XML only to certain depth and limit lists

Tags: java, xml, xstream

For a project, which generates XML-files based on a XSD-file, I want to automatically generate the documentation. *

In this documentation I list the different elements defined in the XSD.
And for each element I want to show an example of that element.
The problem is, that the XML-example might be quite long and contains a lot of children.
Therefore I want to shorten the example by:

- limiting the shown depth
- limiting the amount of elements in a list

For the root-element that example might look like the following:

```
<root>
  <elements>
    <element>...<element>
    <element>...<element>
    <element>...<element>
    ...
  </elements>
</root>
```

**My approach:**

To generate classes from the XSD and to generate and validate the XML files I use JAXB.
But I could not figure out how to marshal a Non-Root element.
Therefore I am generating my examples with XStream.

To limit the XML-example I am trying to decorate the `PrettyPrintWriter`, but that seems to be quite cumbersome.
The two decorators can be seen in my answer.
I just did not expect to care about the internals of a library for such a (common?) feature.

Is there an easier way to do this? (I can also use another library than XStream, or none at all.)

*
My approach is influenced by [Spring Auto Rest Docs](https://github.com/ScaCap/spring-auto-restdocs)

Answer (score 0):

To limit the shown depth I created the following XStream `WriterWrapper`. The class can wrap for example a `PrettyPrintWriter` and ensures that the wrapped writer only receives the nodes above a given depth threshold.

```
public class RestrictedPrettyPrintWriter extends WriterWrapper {

 private final ConverterLookup converterLookup;
 private final int maximalDepth;
 private int depth;

 public RestrictedPrettyPrintWriter(HierarchicalStreamWriter sw, ConverterLookup converterLookup, int maximalDepth) {
  super(sw);
  this.converterLookup = converterLookup;
  this.maximalDepth = maximalDepth;
 }

 @Override public void startNode(String name, Class clazz) {
  Converter converter = this.converterLookup.lookupConverterForType(clazz);
  boolean isSimpleType = converter instanceof SingleValueConverter;
  _startNode(name, !isSimpleType);
 }

 @Override public void startNode(String name) {
  _startNode(name, false);
 }

 @Override public void endNode() {
  if (_isLessDeepThanMaximalDepth() || _isMaximalDepthReached()) {
   super.endNode();
  }
  depth--;
 }

 @Override public void addAttribute(String key, String value) {
  if (_isLessDeepThanMaximalDepth() || _isMaximalDepthReached()) {
   super.addAttribute(key, value);
  }
 }

 @Override public void setValue(String text) {
  if (_isLessDeepThanMaximalDepth() || _isMaximalDepthReached()) {
   super.setValue(text);
  }
 }

 /**
  * @param name name of the new node
  * @param isComplexType indicates if the element is complex or contains a single value
  */
 private void _startNode(String name, boolean isComplexType) {
  depth++;
  if (_isLessDeepThanMaximalDepth()) {
   super.startNode(name);
  } else if (_isMaximalDepthReached()) {
   super.startNode(name);
   /* 
    * set the placeholder value now
    * setValue() will never be called for complex types 
    */
   if (isComplexType) {
    super.setValue("...");
   }
  }
 }

 private boolean _isMaximalDepthReached() {
  return depth == maximalDepth;
 }

 private boolean _isLessDeepThanMaximalDepth() {
  return depth < maximalDepth;
 }

}
```

To limit the lists, I tried, in a first attempt, to modify the XStream `CollectionConverter`. But this approach was not general enough because implicit lists do not use this converter.

Therefore I created another `WriterWrapper` which counts the consecutive occurrences of elements with the same name.

```
public class RestrictedCollectionWriter extends WriterWrapper {

 private final int maxConsecutiveOccurences;

 private int depth;
 /** Contains one element per depth.
  *  More precisely: the current element and its parents.
  */
 private Map < Integer, Elements > elements = new HashMap < > ();

 public RestrictedCollectionWriter(HierarchicalStreamWriter sw, int maxConsecutiveOccurences) {
  super(sw);
  this.maxConsecutiveOccurences = maxConsecutiveOccurences;
 }

 @Override public void startNode(String name, Class clazz) {
  _startNode(name);
 }

 @Override public void startNode(String name) {
  _startNode(name);
 }

 @Override public void endNode() {
  if (_isCurrentElementPrintable()) {
   super.endNode();
  }
  depth--;
 }

 @Override public void addAttribute(String key, String value) {
  if (_isCurrentElementPrintable()) {
   super.addAttribute(key, value);
  }
 }

 @Override public void setValue(String text) {
  if (_isCurrentElementPrintable()) {
   super.setValue(text);
  }
 }

 /**
  * @param name name of the new node
  */
 private void _startNode(String name) {
  depth++;
  Elements currentElement = this.elements.getOrDefault(depth, new Elements());
  this.elements.put(depth, currentElement);

  Elements parent = this.elements.get(depth - 1);
  boolean parentPrintable = parent == null ? true : parent.isPrintable();
  currentElement.setName(name, parentPrintable);

  if (currentElement.isPrintable()) {
   super.startNode(name);
  }
 }

 private boolean _isCurrentElementPrintable() {
  Elements currentElement = this.elements.get(depth);
  return currentElement.isPrintable();
 }

 /**
  * Evaluates if an element is printable or not.
  * This is based on the concurrent occurences of the element's name
  * and if the parent element is printable or not.
  */
 private class Elements {
  private String name = "";
  private int concurrentOccurences = 0;
  private boolean parentPrintable;

  public void setName(String name, boolean parentPrintable) {
   if (this.name.equals(name)) {
    concurrentOccurences++;
   } else {
    concurrentOccurences = 1;
   }
   this.name = name;
   this.parentPrintable = parentPrintable;
  }

  public boolean isPrintable() {
   return parentPrintable && concurrentOccurences <= maxConsecutiveOccurences;
  }
 }
}
```

The following listing shows, how the two classes can be used.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrettyPrintWriter pw = new PrettyPrintWriter(sw);
RestrictedCollectionWriter cw = new RestrictedCollectionWriter(pw, 3);
xstream.marshal(objectToMarshal, new RestrictedPrettyPrintWriter(cw, xstream.getConverterLookup(), 3));
```